# How to start Ubuntu from Wubi

Tags: installation, wubi, live-cd

I'm having a hard time in turning on the Ubuntu!  When I open it, it shows me that I must use some Wubi program and when I do. It give me 2 options

1. Demo and full installation
2. Learn more

And when I choose option 1 it give me 3 more options:

1. Reboot now
2. I want to manually reboot later
3. Help me to boot from CD

   - finish

And when I finish Ubuntu closes. Can some one tell me another way of turning on this program.

Comment: You will also find a third option i guess, install within windows. Choose it. If you cant find it, choose help me boot from cd. That will get you working. (assuming u have a real cd and did not mount an iso on virtual disk.)

Comment: Wubi's install inside windows has been disabled for 12.04 which you can bypass as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-by-using-wubi (if you don't want that you need to boot from CD as mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to check what is Ubuntu, is to record and image on CD and let the PC boot from CD when it is turned on. Then You will start so called Live Ubuntu, which is not installed on Your PC, so You can test it and see if You like it.

[More info and download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is an OS, and so it needs to be installed first on your computer. Or else, you can test-drive it on Live mode, that will get automatically started if you boot from the CD, DVD or any other installation medium. You can also download Unetbootin, a program that creates a pendrive with ubuntu installer loaded on it.

Since you are new, I suggest you first run it live from CD, as misery said. You can also use Wubi, or WIndows Based Ubuntu Installer, which doesn't create any additional partition but just installs Ubuntu like any other program inside windows. Install it using Wubi and set your preferences such as username, password, how much space you want to give it, etc. and reboot. The boot menu will how you the option to boot into Ubuntu.

But this doesn't give you the full experience of Ubuntu, as the speed will be slightly less.

And as for backtrack 5, it's another linux distro mainly aimed at breaking security etc. You will have to install it otherwise, to get full experience. Or else, you can perhaps install Back Track 5 tools on Ubuntu. See this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1761143

And by the way, welcome to Ubuntu. :-)