# No Install along Windows option in 12.04 cd

Tags: 12.04, wubi, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install 12.04 inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

I have downloaded 12.04 CD via torrent from Ubuntu site.
When i mount the CD on MagicDisk it does not show the Install along Windows (something like that) option. How can i do that and why isn't it available?

Thanking You.
Salik Sadruddin Merani
Developer and Co-Owner of  [G.Nomote](http://www.gnomote.tk) - world is just a gesture away...

EDIT:

this is the picture of the Window:
http://www.gnomote.tk/extra_images/ubuntu.JPG

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows (also you don't have to mount it with virtual disk - you can download wubi.exe separately and run it with the iso in the same folder)

Comment: Thanks the command worked perfectly with RUN and CMD both :D
the command is [CD-DRIVE]:\wubi.exe --force-wubi
this is for others looking for the same answer

Answer (score 0):

If you mean installing in a separate partition you will have to shrink your windows partition manually as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions), and then create a new partition and install ubuntu in it.

The other alternative is the [Windows UBuntu Installer (WUBI)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) which will install Ubuntu from within windows. I would definitely recommend this method to someone wanting to just try out Ubuntu for the first time.

Comment: Wubi isnt giving the option to install within ubuntu

Comment: posted the pic at top to make it more understandable