# Can I install Ubuntu with windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Can I oops install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Ubuntu and Windows 8.

First I installed Windows 8 and after this I installed Ubuntu,  but not inside Windows 8. I installed it on a separate partition and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine on most PCs. <s>If you've never used Ubuntu before I'd recommend trying the Windows Installer(WUBI) to make a Temporary Ubuntu Install and try it out first. After you've finished with it you just Uninstall it from "Add/Remove Programs" in Windows.</s> *EDIT: WUBI currently has issues with Windows 8 that have yet to be resolved see [This Post](https://askubuntu.com/a/168619/41387).*

If you feel you want a permanent install of Ubuntu please refer to this guide:
[WindowsDualBoot - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: Ah, fixing it now

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I believe to have solved- it is like this problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225028/dual-boot-windows-8-with-ubuntu-12-10/225031#225031)

My suggestion (and it's only a suggestion) is to tpe "msconfig" (without the quotes) on the Windows 8 start screen. In the boot tab, see if Ubuntu is listed. If it is, select the entry by highlighting it and click on "Set as default". This should hopefully load the Ubuntu bootloader instead of Windows' boot menu allowing you you boot into Ubuntu.

Also, from the start screen type in "uefi" and in the settings option on the seach charm, click on "Advanced start up options", click on it. Scroll down to the bottom of the entry and under "Advanced start up", click Restart now. You should now have an option to change the boot order.

I know it is the same solution to another one but to me the core problem is the same- Windows 8 bootloader

Hope this works!

Ben