# Asus Windows 8 will not let me install Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04

I am having difficulties getting Ubuntu installed on my laptop and I have tried a few different ways of going about this as suggested on the disk. They include a direct install, install within windows and install helper. None of these worked and I do not like or want Windows on my laptop. How can I get rid of Windows and get Ubuntu to install on my computer?

NOTE: Autorun does not work on this laptop for some reason and I am thinking that this may be part of the issue. Please help if you can. Thank you in advance.

~~~UBUNTU INSTALL SOURCE:
Disc: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Desktop Edition

~~~LAPTOP COMPUTER INFORMATION:
OS: Windows 8 (Current)
System: 2.7 Windows Experience Index
Processor: AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.00 GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 4.00 (3.69 GB Useable)
System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
Pen and Touch: No Pen or Touch is available for display.

~~~ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Windows Boot Manager

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  

To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."  
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer  
for assistance.   

  File: \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr  

  Status: 0xc0000007b  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required  
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

Comment: Why are you installing 10.04LTS?

Comment: I suggest to read the UEFI guide for Ubuntu. Most Windows 7 or Windows 8 computers come with UEFI firmware. If I might ask, why are you using 10.04? Hardware support is much better in more recent versions, especially on EFI computers I'd strongly suggest to try 12.04 LTS and if that doesn't work, try 13.04... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) Note that if you're trying to create an Ubuntu installation in a preinstalled Windows 8 or 8.1 system *using Wubi*, [that will not work](http://askubuntu.com/a/225082/22949).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Ubuntu you are trying to install is very outdated use the following Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit version to install on your computer:

[Thank you | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)

Just install from CD or USB and if you can clean install it would be the best option as you have problems with erasing windows boot and you have a very old Ubuntu OS, hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry for not doing a follow up. As it turns out the computer was c**p and so I moved on to a better one and all is well with Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you kindly for all of the replies and I do hope that this information will help others in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, insert your disk, then shutdown your computer. Then reboot and when you see the boot screen with the Asus logo press the button available for you to be able to boot into the CD (should be "Esc" for Asus Computers), then select the cd drive. You should then be able to go through the instalation. Make sure you select "Remove Windows 8 and install Ubuntu" when installing.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the disc in which you have windows installed if you dont have any important data..

**IF you have USB drive**

Make a live cd of one of the tools given below

- Hirens boot
- Acronics
- Ubuntu (it self)

Run from usb and delete/format the partition (TO RUN FROM USB go to BIOS and change the boot squence) 
create new partition and install UBUNTU 
try this if its works.

Answer (score 0):

Even I brought a new Lap from HP and its pre-loaded with windows 8. I tried to install 32bit ubuntu 10.04 with bootable cd which I used to install in my windows 7 PC. I got the same error. I have tried changing the boot order and disabling the feature called secure boot. Still it didn't worked. After a lot of research I found in ubuntu forum that only ubuntu 12 and above can be used to install side by side in windows 8. Because windows 8 has some new setting which prevents the user to install any other OS side by side or even replacing windows 8, and only ubuntu 12 and higher version is compatible with this feature. Even in youtube you won't find a tutorial which explains how to install ubuntu 10.04 in windows 8 pc. It has only ubuntu 12 and above OS tutorial.

Comment: Yep, this feature is called **Secure Boot** and may be turned off. The problem is that old Ubuntu versions do not support UEFI.

Comment: Why the hell would somebody want to install ubuntu 10.04 on a brand new machine? *confused*

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation.  I must use a Texas Instruments SDK that will only run on Ubuntu 10.04.  I tried using Ubuntu as a guest in Virtualbox running on a Windows 7 host, but was having trouble getting hardware (SD Card) to work properly.  Decided to buy a new cheap laptop to dual boot Windows or Ubuntu 10.04.  New laptop came with Windows 8.  I am going to remove Windows 8 and install Ubuntu 10.04 as the sole OS.