# Installing Ubuntu with the Windows installer?

Tags: installation, grub2

Is it safe as instructions said?
If I install Ubuntu by this way, could I while updating Ubuntu update grub?
because I saw this way install Ubuntu, when start Ubuntu is using Windows's boot manager.

Comment: Why not install it virtually with VirtualBox?

Comment: What do you mean by the Windows installer. Is this using wubi? What do you mean by "safety"?

Answer (score 1):

You should know this about Wubi: [Wubi - Pros and Cons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/wubi-pros-and-cons)...

#### Pros

- If a computer needs to have Linux installed temporarily, Wubi is easier to remove without leaving obvious traces. Without Wubi, you need to re-enlarge the Windows partition and restore the Windows bootloader. With Wubi, you just use the supplied uninstaller. You can even temporarily hide the Ubuntu entry from the Windows bootloader.
- For someone who wants to try out Linux but is afraid of harming Windows, Wubi is less scary.

#### Cons

- Suppose a user has a computer with Wubi, has upgraded something but isn't sure what, is thousands of kilometers away, and phones you because his computer won't get past the bootloader stage. What next? There are far fewer resources about troubleshooting Wubi than with traditional Grub-based dual boot.
- Similarly, if you need to troubleshooting or rescue the system with a live CD, Wubi reduces your options.
- Increasing the size of the Wubi partition image wasn't supported last time I looked.
- Wubi induces a small performance loss. (But if you're even considering Wubi, you probably don't care.)
- If Windows screws up its filesystem, you lose Linux as well. (Though I get the feeling NTFS is reliable these days.)
- Doesn't work with UEFI and if Windows 8 or above is preinstalled.

---

Related links:

- Ubuntu Wiki: [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)
- AskUbuntu post: [Can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-ubuntu-inside-windows)
- AskUbuntu post: [How to boot WUBI installed Ubuntu within Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168608/how-to-boot-wubi-installed-ubuntu-within-windows-8)

Comment: thanks @user68186, updated my answer with the con that you've pointed in the comments...

Answer (score -1):

Installing ubuntu on windows is safe. Get the installer by typing "wubi ubuntu".
After you follow the instructions, you'll have ubuntu and the original windows! Try it. It's free and safe.