# How can I install Ubuntu on a Dell inspiron 17R 7720 SE with Windows 8?

Tags: 12.10, windows, wubi

I recently bought a Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 Special Edition but I am unable to install Ubuntu 12.10. WUBI does not work for me and I am wondering if there is another way to install it my machine came with windows 8 pre installed.

Comment: "Does not work" is a little vague. Are you saying you don't want to use WUBI or that it literally doesn't work? If its the latter, do you get any errors? What happens when you try to use WUBI?

Comment: @seth [Wubi does not work with UEFI/Windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168608/how-to-boot-wubi-installed-ubuntu-within-windows-8).

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work on my machine (HP ENVY Dv6 Win 8 preinstalled UEFI bios)i had to go into bios and disable fast-boot and also enable legacy boot for it to work. it warned me that windows 8 might not work afterwards but it did. Another issue i ran into was with the usb3 drivers as those had to be disabled before boot for it to work also. Best of luck