# will booting Ubuntu in my samsung np550p5c-s06in brick it?

Tags: boot, wubi, uefi, samsung

i bought this laptop in july,2013... and it was manufactured in march... i wanted to dual boot it with ubuntu (using wubi) and windows 8.1(running now). can it harm my computer? if yes then is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: You can't use Wubi with Windows 8. http://askubuntu.com/a/225082/169736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, WUBI is useless on a computer that uses EFI to boot. Don't even bother trying to use it.

Beyond that, the Samsung "bricking" problem has been worked around by new kernel features. I don't know precisely when Ubuntu implemented these features, but I'd be shocked if they weren't available in the latest release (13.10). If you want to be absolutely sure, you can install and use Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode -- but this is awkward unless you also convert Windows to boot in the same way. The least awkward way to mix boot modes is to use my [rEFInd boot manager:](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Install it in Windows, add `hdbios` to the `scanfor` options in `refind.conf`, and install Ubuntu in BIOS mode.