# how to install ubuntu 14.0.1 inside/alongside windows 8.1 preinstalled laptop?

Tags: 14.04

I have purchased a new laptop with windows 8.1 preinstalled. I want to use ubuntu 14.0.1 on my laptop without uninstalling windows. I have created bootable usb stick for installing ubuntu. But when i open wubi.exe install inside windows option is not there.
Is there something like you can't install ubuntu 14.0.1 inside windows? 
If not, then how do i accomplish this task?

Comment: [You won't be able to use Wubi on your computer that came with Windows 8 preinstalled](http://askubuntu.com/a/225082/22949), but you can create a regular (non-Wubi) installation alongside your Windows system: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/22949)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome aboard to Linux!
Bad news first - You can no longer use wubi.exe to install (dual boot) Ubuntu.

Good news is you can dual boot Windows 8.1 & Ubuntu 14.04

Follow the below links

[AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

[ItsFoss](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)

It may look longer but it worked for me.