# Windows installer for Ubuntu not available anymore?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, wubi

In my Windows 8, I am trying to install Ubuntu in a new partition I´ve made. I am following a tutorial, and it says that I can get the Windows Installer from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

However, the installer is not there anymore.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu with this installer from Windows 8 or this is not possible anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: see amongst others on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168608/how-to-boot-wubi-installed-ubuntu-within-windows-8

Comment: So it won`t work I am afraid ,right? :-(

Comment: No. You can install Ubuntu with Virtualbox or VMWare in Windows or the other way around. Or use a dual boot.

Comment: I have a burned DVD with Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to install it, but it´s not recognizing Windows 8 and I am afraid to lost it if I proceed. I made a partition in dev/sda4 to install it, but I am not sure about this...If I choose dev/sda4, will it break the Windows system on the other partition?

Comment: Maybe you want to start using a Virtual Box? That's what I suggest. Later, install Ubuntu, and run Windows as Virtual Box, if needed anymore at all :)

Comment: If you decide on dual-boot see http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

No, windows 8 is not supported by WUBI. It is normally shipped inside the ubuntu ISO, and if one copies the wubi.exe out of the CD, you can use it for wubi based installation. Read the [post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596) from one of the Developers.