# Unable to install 12.04 along side with Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install 12.04 inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

Previously I got Ubuntu 11.04 installed with Wubi. Work perfectly. Then I got this new update of 12.04, download the ISO, burned into CD. Tried to install within windows, it asked me to reboot into CD.

I did just that, boot into the language option. Chose English. Next, it is the option to choose update and Internet connection. I didn't want to connect to Internet at the time cause I got slow connection.

Next, it asked me to choose from 3 option. I choose option1: which is dual boot, install Ubuntu along side with Windows. Then, the installer suddenly jumped into conclusion, ejecting my DVD-ROM. Ask me to take out the CD and Press Enter to restart.

After restart, I boot into the dual boot option, choose the Ubuntu but it give me wubi error. So I uninstall Ubuntu with Program and Features from Control Panel. Manually remove the Ubuntu boot option with EasyBCD.

I restart the installation with same step. Now it boot me directly into Windows without Ubuntu.

PC specs:

- Windows 7 ultimate 64bit
- AMD Athlon II X4 620
- ECS 780G Ultra
- 4GB DDR2 800 RAM
- 500GB Western D sata drive

Comment: Installing within Windows using a CD has been disabled by default in 12.04 - see here to bypass: http://askubuntu.com/a/125163/14916 The only options Wubi gives from CD are to 'reboot and install normally' (from CD) or the 'CD boot helper' which uses a Wubi mechanism to boot the CD if your BIOS doesn't support it.

Comment: @EliahKagan I should probably have marked it as a duplicate to the questions I linked to. I think it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled ubuntu with wubi.exe (2mb+)
This time, I need to download ubuntu again from the internet. It took me 2 hour.
Finally it done. Im able to dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu.

But Im still wondering why my ubuntu CD didn't work?? I don't want to wait for 2 hour every time I need install ubuntu on other pc...

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. This is not an answer, please edit your question to add details or create a new one. Thank you.