# Only Wubi needed ..not the Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install 12.04 inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

First, thanks for taking time to answer my question.

My question is that I have ubuntu 12.04 with me but no Wubi is in there..its asking me to do a regular Ubuntu installation instead of Wubi installation in my windows.

So I only need the Wubi not the Ubuntu installation files..How do I make sure that Wubi installation file I will download form Ubuntu.com will not initiate a download of Ubuntu 12.04 again as I already have the installation ISO with me and Direct Wubi to use that ISO to install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/125015/14916

Comment: @BCBC ...thanks ..the command wubi.exe --force-wubi worked perfectly and gave me what I was looking for..thanks again for this help. I also thanks "Ignite", "Bodhi.zazen" and "Roland Taylor" for earlier help with the installation. see you guys somewhere in future and Have a good life.

Comment: @WoodenPaw - please say thanks by clicking the tick button next to the answer that help you most.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Wubi from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).
Also have a look at installation [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

Comment: Thanks..but my questions remains same that How I make sure that Wubi will not download Ubuntu 12.04 because I have Ubuntu 12.04 ISO with me which does not have Wubi (Ubuntu installation in windows). when I execute the Wubi from Windows it is not giving me option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows..its giving me only one Option "Demo and Full installation" the Demo is the Ubuntu Demo from CD/USB ..not Wubi Ubuntu installation in Windows. So I only need Wubi installation which will help me to install Ubuntu alongside windows..not the Wubi which will start downloading the Ubuntu 12.04 again

Comment: Put the .iso in the same directory (folder) as wubi.exe

Comment: Also make sure that your Wubi version matches with your Ubuntu Version.

Comment: Hi...I extracted the Ubuntu from ISO and downloaded the Wubi and kept it in the same folder where Ubuntu was extracted form ISO and still Wubi trying to download Ubuntu 12.04. One more thing, is there a different installation file for Intel processor and AMD processor as I have Intel processor and the Ubuntu installation file says "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64". Thanks for the answers so far and thanks in advance for future help & answers.

Comment: Don't extract the iso and then try running Wubi.

Comment: same thing ..still downloading the Ubuntu and I have Ubuntu iso mounted in Daemon tool.

Comment: Then most probably your Wubi does not match with your Ubuntu version.Download Wubi from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: Sorry..same thing again after downloading the Wubi from your given link. its still downloading the Ubuntu and not recognizing that I have a mounted ISO in the Daemon Tool.

Comment: That only means that the version of Ubuntu you are using is not compatible with the Wubi.I would suggest that you download a fresh copy of Ubuntu or install Ubuntu alongside with Windows.

Comment: If you insist on running it using Daemon Tool then it's the same as running it from a CD - you need to supply `--force-wubi` (see my link posted as comment to your question). If instead you place wubi.exe and the iso in the same directory as already suggested, it will use the iso (provided it is valid and you have the correct version of wubi.exe).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the wubi exe that is on the CD/USB from within Windows in order to get a Wubi install. If you run the CD/LiveUSB after restarting the system, it will not give you the option to install inside Windows.

Comment: well thats what I am trying to say the when I execute the Wubi from Windows it is not giving me option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows..its giving me only one Option "Demo and Full installation" the Demo is the Ubuntu Demo from CD/USB ..not Wubi Ubuntu installation in Windows....So I only need Wubi installation which will help me to install Ubuntu alongside windows..not the Wubi which will start downloading the Ubuntu 12.04 again as I already have the Ubuntu ISO with me.

Comment: @WoodenPaw: is there any reason you do not want to install Ubuntu the normal way? You would be better off doing that and you can still keep Windows.

Comment: I do not have CD/DVD & USB drive with me and I have no plan in 1 month to purchase it and I am dying to get my hand on new Ubuntu..lol..so as I previously installed and used Ubuntu "natty" through Wubi so I was expecting the same thing with 12.04.