# Does installing Ubuntu erase your partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu, and I backed up my stuff on a partition in the SSD that I'm going to be installing Ubuntu on.  Is Ubuntu going to erase that partition on the SSD that I'm installing to?

Also does anyone know where to backup in case Ubuntu will erase those partitions.  I don't have an external HDD or SSD.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  While I'd recommend reading [Is it possible to install Ubuntu without formatting any partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193241/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-formatting-any-partitions), it's a fairly old question, with some fairly outdated answers (WUBI).  I originally marked this question a duplicate of that one, but I think this one can and should stand separate.  That said, others may feel differently and vote-to-close.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438421/edit) to include what operating system you are currently using?  Including your intended uses for Ubuntu might be helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and one more note for potential close-votes -- Note that the question I originally used as a duplicate is specifically about Windows 7.  I think it's safe to say that things are different enough today that Windows 10 or 11 answers will be different.

Comment: "*backed up my stuff on a partition in the SSD that I'm going to be installing Ubuntu on*" many folks would not consider that a *real* backup, which would be onto some other media that would survive the destruction, theft, loss, or corruption of the original media. Because Ubuntu will happily destroy all partitions if you choose an unwise installer selection.

Comment: You decide what gets erased during install, but please do realize its easy to make a mistake & erase everything so you should have good backups.  I have installs I use for QA (*Quality Assurance*) where I re-install the OS 45+ times per year intentionally where its done to ensure no data is lost, plus *manually installed* packages get auto-reinstalled after install process.. so I'd hope I know what I was doing, yet I've still in error wiped a 2TB drive, 10TB disk array...  ie. mistakes are easy to make, so I'd assume you're going to make a mistake & plan for recovery; better safe than sorry

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to not erase the installation destination for Ubuntu, but it's probably not what you want.

First, Ubuntu has to be installed to a compatible file system, which your system probably doesn't have if you haven't already been using some other Linux distribution.  In that case, you need to format (erase) a partition.

Also, even if you somehow had a compatible file system, the Ubuntu installer would still overwrite the space where it needs to install the system.

What you're currently describing as a "backup" is not really an acceptable backup. You need to have some other place to back up your important data. Having data duplicated on a different partition on the same drive doesn't do hardly anything to protect you from the most common causes of data loss.

That's up to you how and where you choose to do backups. We can't tell you what you need to back up and the best way to do it. You need to determine that for yourself based on your own threat model and the importance you put on your data. But you should be aware that if you don't back up your important files, or if you don't put them in a safe or redundant space, it's only a matter of *when* not *if* you're going to lose it.

You're playing with fire to not have good backups in an alternate location before installing operating systems. What if you mess up?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Windows 10 or 11 as your existing OS (a fairly reasonable assumption, I believe), then (as [@Nmath points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/1438426/1165986)), yes, it's likely that you will have to repartition/reformat.  If so, this is a destructive operation and will erase  the existing Windows partition and files.

Also fully agree with @Nmath on the backup topic.  At the very least, I would recommend a purchase of one (preferably two, from different manufacturers) small USB drives to store essential files.  And, of course, always test that you can restore from whatever backup solution you choose.

However, assuming Windows 10 or 11, you also have other options:

- A virtual machine (e.g. VMWare, Hyper-V, VirtualBox)
- My preference for running Ubuntu in Windows is to use [WSL, the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) feature.  This is a fairly lightweight feature which allows running Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions) on Windows without the overhead of a full VM.  There are certain use cases (primarily development or system administration) where this is a fantastic option, but there are also areas where it is more advisable to use a virtual machine (or even a full-blown, dual-boot installation).

  Assuming you are on a recent Windows release, installing Ubuntu on WSL can be as easy as opening PowerShell or CMD as an Administrator and running `wsl --install`.

Answer (score 0):

### No Need for Ubuntu to Erase Partitions when Installing

**Step By Step** - Caution, Windows bootloader will be replaced by GRUB. Instructions for backup are not included in this answer.

- Use **Windows Disk Management** to create space for the new Ubuntu partition on the SSD, GParted is not recommended.
- Create Ubuntu Live or Persistent USB for use as installer.
- Boot installer USB and proceed with Ubuntu install.
- Select Language, click "Continue".
- Select Keyboard layout, click "Continue".
- Select Wireless network, (optional), click "Continue".
- Select installation preference and select "Download updates while installing Ubuntu", (optional), and Select "Install third-party software ...", (optional), click "Continue".
- If asked about unmounting partitions that are in use, select Yes, click "Continue".
- Do not use Advanced feature disk encryption for this install method.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else", click "Continue".
- Under Device for boot loader installation select the target drive.
- Select the recently created partition and click change, select use as Ext4, select “format this partition”, and Mount point = "/" then OK.
- Do not edit any other partitions.
- If asked to Write previous changes... click Continue.
- Click Install now.
- Confirm partitions to be formatted if asked, click continue.
- Select your location. click "Continue".
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password. - Click "Continue".
- Wait for installation to complete.

(Your Windows install should now be available in GRUB).