# WUBI won't install on Windows

Tags: installation, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install 12.04 inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

I have a friend who is looking at Ubuntu and he wanted to install it as a Windows app so he could easily uninstall it if he were not interested.

He downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 64bit iso

However the WUBI loader told him to restart the computer with the disc in the tray.
How do you install Ubuntu in Windows?

Comment: Don't mount it - download the 12.04 wubi.exe, save it in the same folder before running. Or if you must mount it, use the command line option `--force-wubi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are instructions to install from a bootable USB stick:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows