# Virtual Box or Disk Partition

Tags: installation, virtualbox

I am a windows7 user and have never used a linux os. I want to try Debian on my machine.  What are the advantages/disadvantages of the following two options?

1) Partition my hard drive and install linux onto the partition.

2) Use virtual box to set up a virtual machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend third option which is installing Ubuntu using Windows Based Installer. This will install Ubuntu like dual boot along with Windows and will allow you to try it like normal OS.

[Read more about Wubi and how to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Virtual Box.  You can create one virtual machine and then try out as many Linux distros as you want.  When you find one you like then go for a dual boot system. 
In my case, Ubuntu is my main OS and I run Windows inside Virtual Box.