# Unable to install Ubuntu Linux 12.04 / 13.04 after downloading file in Windows

Tags: 12.04

Help! After I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 Desktop version, I find that I can't install it, as it doesn't work! It says that its **not a valid win32 application** and I know it's not.

But why is it that, if I use my very old first version of Ubuntu Linux desktop that was delivered to me from Ubuntu - it can still install normally even though it has no updates.

How come this version that I download from your link on the Ubuntu website, is not working? The folder  size is 0kb.

I really wanted to have the 12.04 version of Ubuntu Desktop...
I really want to install Ubuntu inside my Win Xp OS.

I love Ubuntu!!!

Comment: What file are you downloading, exactly? Please include the download link you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu with Wubi?

Comment: To install Ubuntu 12.04 *inside* Windows, so that no new partitions are created and it's not necessary to boot from a live CD/DVD/USB to perform the installation, you should use Wubi. For information on how to do this, see [Wubi's download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows), [this tag wiki](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info), [the Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide), [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/announce.html?t=1639198) (once the forums are back up) and/or [Can I install 12.04 inside Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/125015/22949).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must be downloading the LiveCD version of Ubuntu Desktop. This can not be run under windows, you have to burn it to CD, then reboot your computer.

If your BIOS is correctly set up with the CD/DVD drive as the first boot option, then Ubuntu will start and allow you to install it alongside your version of Windows.