# How to boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 on Aspire One 765

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8, aspire-one

I can't seem to get Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 installed properly alongside Windows 8 on a netbook Acer Aspire One 765.

First thing I tried was with a live usb/bootable usb. This failed after disabling secure boot and putting USB HDD on no.1 on the list. The system does not recognize any usb device although the usb works fine on another laptop.

Then I tried UnetBootin and Wubi. After installation I get a Windows 8 boot menu in which I can choose between w8 and ubuntu.

When I choose Ubuntu I get a screen that says it cannot boot windows because of hardware- or software changes. It needs the Windows install disk.

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubi1dr.mbr

Status: 0xc000007b

Installing with wubi was sort of my last option to finally get Ubuntu on this device but I seem to be stuck with w8 here.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You cannot use wubi, if you have pre-installed Windows 8 with gpt partitioning. http://askubuntu.com/questions/360616/why-was-wubi-removed-from-13-04

Comment: You might also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/330085/can-i-use-wubi-for-manual-installation

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported