# Installing Ubuntu over Win XP

Tags: installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu and put it to DVD and it boots on my laptop running xp but it will not let me install Ubuntu over the xp. What have I or am I doing wrong.
Laptop is Sony Vaio 32 bit 1gig ram.

Comment: duplicated [Can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/125015)

Comment: First of all you have to burn the image (.iso file) onto the DVD using a Disc Burner (such as Nero -for WinXP users-) -not copying it (the .iso file) to the disc-. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @Braiam why would this be a dupicate of 'install ubntu inside windows' when the question clarify Ubuntu will not install Over XP?

Comment: Do you mean the live CD install process starts but can't get past the point where you choose to install over windows? Can you get in to the manual partitioning option?

Comment: So, you want to completely replace XP with Ubuntu. Which model of Sony Vaio do you have? It could be the standard Ubuntu has a problem with Sony's hardware, so I would suggest trying the lighter Ubuntu derivative, Xubuntu from http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/13.10/release/  as well. There's a 32-bit version there as well as a 64-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot post a comment so writing it in answer. Can you please elaborate a bit on what problem are you facing ? Here are the instructions that you should follow for dual boot installation :

Firstly, **I would recommend you to create a backup of all the data.**

**Installing Ubuntu**

If the computer does not boot from the CD (e.g. Windows starts again instead), reboot and check your BIOS settings by pressing F2, F12, Delete, or ESC. Select "boot from CD".
Proceed with installation until you are asked this question: "How do you want to partition the disk?".
If you have already partitioned the disk and left space for Ubuntu, install it to that and then follow the rest of the steps.
Otherwise, choose one of the next two steps.
Automatic partition resizing (recommended)

Choose the first option, which should say "Install them side by side, choosing between them each startup".
Specify the size of the new partition by dragging the slider at the bottom of the window.
Click on "Forward".
Continue on to Finishing Ubuntu Installation

**Manual partitioning**

Choose "Manually edit partition table".
Listed will be your current partitions.
Select the partition you want to resize and press Enter.
Select "Size:", press Enter.
Select Yes, press Enter.
Type in a new size in gigabytes for your partition, it's recommended you free up at least 10 GB of free space for your Ubuntu install. Press Enter when happy with your changes. It may take some time to apply the changes.
Create a swap partition of at least your amount of RAM (if you don't know, 2000 MB is a good value).

Create a partition for your Ubuntu installation.
Create other partitions if necessary.

Select "Finish partitioning and write changes to disk".

Reference : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

If you face any problem please update your question to describe the problem more precisely we will be happy to help you. Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks Shivam I just want to get rid of Microsoft and install Ubuntu no partitions or anything dualboot not required.I am able to do a mount inside windows with 12.04 but would like a clean full install of Ububtu.

Comment: Did you try to change boot order priority from BIOS and then try to boot using Bootable Ubuntu CD/USB ? After that format the complete harddisk (if required) and install fresh ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

You also have the choice of virtualizing Ubuntu within Windows by using the WUBI Installer described in this highly detailed, step-by-step guide at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: Isn't WUBI an abandoned project?

Comment: So's XP. However, since https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide is still up, it may be the least worst solution for coexisting with the least worst version of Windows.

Comment: Trying to dump windows but not able to. Have even tried loading the sbm.bin onto floppy and then changing the sequence.