# If I disable ueif on Windows 8, can I use the Windows installer?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Lenovo u430 laptop and would like to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8. If I disable ueif can I do that and install Ubuntu with the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed many times I assume. Windows 8 uses a bootloader different than Windows 7 / Vista uses. Windows significantly changing its boot system settings & options. Therefore, its pretty much unclear how `wubi` would respond to it. Even in **Ubuntu's** official website under **[Install Ubuntu with the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)** explains;

> > Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.10.

Ubuntu also making a statement [**here**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) as below;

> > With Wubi, our officially supported Ubuntu installer for Windows, you can install and uninstall Ubuntu easily and safely. For 12.04 LTS only.

I would recommend you to install it on a separate partition for Ubuntu on its own. In such case, you may refer [**Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Also refer [**Can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?**](https://askubuntu.com/a/125163/179042) to see more information