# How to install ubuntu 13.10 inside C drive of Windows 8.1

Tags: 13.10, windows-8

I have done this before in my Dell machine.There was an option to install ubuntu inside c drive in win 8.1(It consumes 18 GB of drive space of windows c drive.No need to create different partion to install Ubuntu)

When I tried the same installation method in my friend's HP laptop there was no option like install Ubuntu inside windows.Please tell me how to install Ubuntu inside windows 8.1 (in HP Pavalion)

Thank You.

Comment: That option isn't available anymore in Wubi.

Comment: But I did it yesterday In my Dell Laptop

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the disc and start wubi from the cmd, with the following:

```
wubi.exe --force-wubi
```

This answer is a duplicate . The original lies here: [Can I install Ubuntu inside Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-ubuntu-inside-windows)